# Swift Closing and Then Opening Results in Loading Twice

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I looked at several solutions on SO but none seem to work. I have a problem where when I open and then close an app, it "loads" twice in a row. Is there a way or code to stop this from happening? The app is configured in such a way that when a user closes and then opens the app, the code in the App Delegate sends the app to a "CommandandControlViewController" which devides whether if a user is Signed In, Not Signed In and sends to the appropriate ViewController.

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let yourVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CommandAndControlViewController") as! CommandAndControlViewController

    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = yourVC
    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ***might be*** causing because AppDelegate has its own "window" property and you are creating another "window" in ***applicationWillEnterForeground*** method where app will have two windows, this might be causing it to load twice. Since you are in ***AppDelegate.swift*** no need to create separate ***window*** and use existing one without writing first two lines of code.

I would suggest to write down last 4 lines of your code in ***didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*** method and give it a try. Which will look something like below :

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

      let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      let yourVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CommandAndControlViewController") as! CommandAndControlViewController 

       //Below rootViewController is of type UIViewController hence even you don't cast "yourVC" to CommandAndControlViewController it will work

      window?.rootViewController = yourVC
      window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```